# Error: Unable to read beyond the end of the stream

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have this VB code which is giving the above error in the code below

```
  Try
                'Job Ticket Section
                StatusText = "Reading Job Ticket Data."
                FileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(SoftSavePath, "cfgjt.sys")
                If Not System.IO.File.Exists(FileName) Then
                    CopyDefaultSoftJobTicketItems(FileName, ErrorFlag)
                End If
                filenumber = FreeFile()
                FileOpen(filenumber, FileName, OpenMode.Binary)
                .ConvexJobTicketItems = GetConfigConvexJobTicketItems(filenumber)
                .ConcaveJobTicketItems = GetConfigConcaveJobTicketItems(filenumber)
                FileClose(filenumber)
            Catch ex As Exception
                ErrorFlag.NumErrors = ErrorFlag.NumErrors + 1
                ReDim Preserve ErrorFlag.ErrorDef(ErrorFlag.NumErrors - 1)
                With ErrorFlag.ErrorDef(ErrorFlag.NumErrors - 1)
                    .Number = ErrorFlag.NumErrors - 1
                    .Description = "Open Config job ticket File Error: " & StatusText + ex.Message
                End With
                FileClose(filenumber)
            End Try
```

On debugging , I found out that when the **cursor** hits this statement **.ConcaveJobTicketItems** , it jumps to the catch block .

The function `GetConfigConcaveJobTicketItems(filenumber)` where I stepped into has other function calls inside it .

```
   Public Function GetConfigConcaveJobTicketItems(ByRef InFileNumber As Short) As JobTicketConcaveDesignItemsType
        With GetConfigConcaveJobTicketItems
            .ComfortConic = GetConfigConcaveSphereToricJobTicket(InFileNumber, "ConfortConic")
            .Multicurve = GetConfigConcaveSphereToricJobTicket(InFileNumber, "Multicurve")
        End With
    End Function
```

When the debug cursor Hits the statement  .`ComfortConic = GetConfigConcaveSphereToricJobTicket(InFileNumber, "ConfortConic")`, I step into the function and see that everything is fine and the cursor moves to the next line.

```
.Multicurve = GetConfigConcaveSphereToricJobTicket(InFileNumber, "Multicurve")
```

The `GetConfigConcaveSphereToricJobTicket()` is defined as

```
Public Function GetConfigConcaveSphereToricJobTicket(ByRef InFileNumber As Short, ByRef InString As String) As JobTicketSphereToricConcaveItemsType
        With GetConfigConcaveSphereToricJobTicket
            .Sphere = GetConfigConcaveDesignJobTicket(InFileNumber, InString & "Sphere")
            .Toric = GetConfigConcaveDesignJobTicket(InFileNumber, InString & "Toric")
        End With
    End Function
```

Comment: None of the methods you have posted appear to be reading the file. The problem is that you're asking for data that is not in the file. In the Debug -> Exceptions window tick Thrown for all clr exceptions. Then the debugger will break at the exact spot the problem is. From there you should be able to diagnose why you're over-reading the file.

Comment: Your code looks like it started as VB6 project.  `InFileNumber` should be declared as an `Integer` not a `Short` (this could be the result of an improper conversion ; see: [FileSystem.FreeFile Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.freefile(v=vs.110).aspx).  Please post the code for `GetConfigConcaveDesignJobTicket'.